# What is the easiest way to share .html files with work colleagues in the Microsoft Ecosystem?

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint, microsoft-teams

I am a data analyst who works with R a lot. As a result, most of my outputs are in the form of  .html files (Rmarkdown, leaflet maps, plotly, d3.js, flexdashboard... etc).

What is the easiest/most frictionless way I can share these files with my colleagues in any Microsoft application?

For example, assume I have made the following leaflet map which I want to share with someone at work:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"/>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <style>#map { height: 200px; }</style>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
      var center = [-33.8650, 151.2094];
      var map = L.map('map').setView(center, 3);
      L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {maxZoom: 18}).addTo(map);
      L.marker(center).addTo(map);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I can't seem to find **anywhere** in the Microsoft ecosystem (Teams, Sharepoint, Onedrive, Power BI... etc) where I can easily display the contents of this file. For example, if I upload the file to Teams, Sharepoint or Onedrive, there is no way that any of these applications can preview the contents of the file. The following image is what happens when I open it in either Teams, Sharepoint or Onedrive:

[image]

Therefore, you would have to download every file locally and open in a browser. This is not an ideal solution. I can't host these online either as the data is private. Where is the best place to put these files in order to share with my colleagues easily?

Comment: Is it feasible to print to pdf? Teams has much better pdf support then raw html file, if it's an option for you?

Comment: Thank you for you comment @HiltonGiesenow. I guess I could do this, although I would loose the interactability which is why I use .html files in the first place. I can't even find anywhere with the option "Open in Browser" which would solve the problem as well.

Comment: yes, you're relying on the native file browser, and for html there's really not much handling, I don't think. You could possible look at another option - writing a "custom tab" app for Teams, which basically just 'iframes' your pages in (like maybe a "listing" page and then a page to host the html files)

Comment: take a look here:
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/93140/office-365-open-html-document-in-browser-in-document-library Shapoint “solution”

Comment: Thank you Matej and HiltonGiesenow for your feedback. It seems the best option is rename the file from .html to .aspx as Matej suggested. Then upload the file to OneDrive, and add the web link to the OneDrive file as a tab in Teams, as HiltonGiesenow suggested. This makes sharing the files very easy! The only additional step is to ensure all colleagues are given access to the OneDrive folder.

Comment: @RayLarone, You can preview uploaded htm file in browser using "Open in" option provided at 3 dots of uploaded file. That will preview your file in browser. 
Is there any issue in this approach?

Comment: I had the same need and my solution did not rely to the MS ecosystem. I used github pages to host my html/web content. So if you have github in your company or use it to version your files as well, this may be also a good way for you. (Old sharepoints could host web content in the past but not the new/m365 ones)

Answer (score 1):

You can try and use a browser extension such as "SingleFile" which encapsulates everything (or a lot at least) into one single file, including images, css, scripts, etc.

See github repo: https://github.com/gildas-lormeau/SingleFile

I use this quite often to share gigantic files (sometimes touching the 100mb) with the Brave broeser and it works well. Only downside for me at this moment is that I can't automate the "singlefile" html generation yet.

Comment: This is actually the only forking way in existence how to share a document including embedded images across all OSes and devices if you don't want to use PDF, which renders terribly on most devices and has useless "paper" pages. Kudos for this idea!

Answer (score 0):

The Visual Studio Live Share extension for Visual Studio 2017 or Visual Studio Code might be the answer. Visual Studio and VSCode are owned by Microsoft and fit well in the Microsoft ecosystem.

The Visual Studio Live Share extension allows you to share your code and quickly collaborate on the same codebase without the need to synchronize code or to configure the same development tools, settings, or environment.

You will find more on the following link:
https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2017/11/15/live-share

Comment: Thank you @JanTheMan for your answer. In my case, however, I am not trying to share code. Rather, I am trying to share the actually html page (containing data outputs) with a non technical audience.